# How to give unique row id to rows in display tag table?

Tags: javascript, displaytag, delete-row

I am using display tag to show user list on my JSP. I have a delete button in each row to delete the particular row/ user from the list. For this I am using ajax.

The user is getting deleted from the database using ajax. But since I am using ajax. Untill I refresh the page the user is still there in the display tag list.

Is there any way i can delete the row from display table using javascript?

As far as I think row can be delted from table using javascript but you need to know row id at least.

So, how do I give unique row ids to each row in the display table?

please help.

Below is my code

```
<display:table name="employeeUpdateList" pagesize="50" 
    class="listingTable" keepStatus="true" cellpadding="0px"
    cellspacing="0px" id="employeeUpdate" export="true" requestURI="">
    <display:setProperty name="export.decorated" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename"
        value="Employee Update List.xls" />
    <display:column title="What is changed" property="columnName"></display:column>
    <display:column title="From" property="oldValue"></display:column>
    <display:column title="To" property="newValue"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Effective Date">
        <fmt:formatDate value="${employeeUpdate.effectiveDate}"
            pattern="dd MMMM yyyy" />
    </display:column>
    <display:column title="Changed By" property="changedBy.fullname"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Changed On">
        <fmt:formatDate value="${employeeUpdate.changedOn }"
            pattern="dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss" />
    </display:column>
    <display:column media="html"
        style="text-align :center!important;padding:0px!important">
        <input class="input-button-small" type="button"
            value="<spring:message code='button.delete' />"
            onclick="deleteEmployeeUpdate('${deleteEmployeeUpdateUrl}','${employeeUpdate.id}')" />
    </display:column>
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name"
        value="Employee Update" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name"
        value="Employee updates " />
</display:table>
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery you could just do this in the click event of the button: `$(this).parent('tr').remove()`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. I have added my code.

Comment: @Ashish: Good deal, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** - now that you've posted your code, I see you're using DOM0 `onclick="..."` handlers. I don't recommend doing that (see below, this is a classic use case for doing event delegation — watching for clicks at the table level rather than on individual buttons), but..

You'll want to modify your `deleteEmployeeUpdate` function to accept another argument, which will be the button that was clicked. So:

```
onclick="deleteEmployeeUpdate(this, '${deleteEmployeeUpdateUrl}','${employeeUpdate.id}')"
```

and

```
function deleteEmployeeUpdate(button, url, id) {
    // ...
}
```

Then to remove the row containing the button, within that function:

```
var row = button.parentNode;
while (row && row.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "tr") {
    row = row.parentNode;
}
if (row) {
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

See below for a solution using event delegation, and below that, some handy reading.

---

You don't need to give your rows IDs. When you process the `click` event on the delete button, normally you have a reference to that delete button element as `this`. It has a [`parentNode` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317) which is the node (element) that contains it. That's probably a table cell (`td`). *It* also has a `parentNode` property, which is presumably the row (`tr`), which also has a parent which is usually a `tbody`, etc.

You can remove a row by calling its parent node's [`removeChild` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1734834066) and passing in the `tr` element.

Here's a complete example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/acumof) | [source](http://jsbin.com/acumof/edit)

HTML:

```
<table id="theTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>First row</td><td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Second row</td><td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Third row</td><td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fourth row</td><td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {

  // Get a reference to the table
  var theTable = document.getElementById("theTable");

  // Watch for clicks
  hookEvent(theTable, "click", function(event) {
    var elm, row, tbody;
    elm = event.target
    while (elm && elm.className !== "delete") {
      elm = elm.parentNode;
    }
    if (elm) {
      // It's the delete button, remove this row
      row = elm.parentNode.parentNode; // Parent of button's parent
      tbody = row.parentNode;
      tbody.removeChild(row);
    }
  });

  // === Basic utility functions

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }

  function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    // Very quick-and-dirty, recommend using a proper library,
    // this is just for the purposes of the example.
    if (typeof element.addEventListener !== "undefined") {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    else if (typeof element.attachEvent !== "undefined") {
      element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function(event) {
        return handler(event || window.event);
      });
    }
    else {
      throw "Browser not supported.";
    }
  }
})();
```

Reading:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

---

FWIW, I'd strongly recommend using a good JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). The example gets dramatically shorter, which shows how you can focus on what you're trying to build rather than mucking about with the details of the low-level DOM API.

For example, the above using jQuery: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/acumof/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/acumof/2/edit)

HTML:

*(No change)*

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#theTable").on("click", "button.delete", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

That's for jQuery 1.7 and later. If you're using something earlier, you'd use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) rather than [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (note the order of arguments changes):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#theTable").delegate("button.delete", "click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

It would be similarly simple with just about any of the other libraries.